# Get UITabBarController on presented ViewController/NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am presenting a Navigation Controller from a TabbarController

```
let planSettingsVC = PlanSettingsViewController.instantiateFromStoryboard()
let planInfoNavCon = UINavigationController(rootViewController: planSettingsVC)

if let myTabBarVC = self.tabBarController as? MyPlanTabBarController {
        myTabBarVC.present(planInfoNavCon, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

`PlanInfoNavCon` gets presented and now I want to access the TabBarController that presented it.

Found in Library:

> ```
> open var tabBarController: UITabBarController? { get } // If the view controller has a tab bar controller as its ancestor, return it. Returns nil otherwise.
> ```

So I tried the following on `PlanSettingsViewController`

1. `print(self.tabBarController)` Prints **nil**
2. `print(self.presentingViewController.tabBarController)` Prints **nil**
3. `print(self.navigationController?.presentingViewController?.tabBarController)` Prints **nil**
4. `print(self.navigationController.tabBarController)` Prints **nil**
5. `self.navigationController?.presentingViewController as? MyPlanTabBarController` Results in **nil**

I am able to access TabBarController on ViewController of TabBar by `self.tabBarController` but

How do I access the TabBarController which presented this?

P.S.

`po self.navigationController` returns `<UINavigationController>` and `po self.navigationController?.presentingViewController` returns `<UIViewController>`

[image: lldb]

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
if let myTabBarVC = self.tabBarController as? MyPlanTabBarController {
        myTabBarVC.present(planInfoNavCon, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

says: "Present planInfoNavCon *from* self.tabBarController"

Curious... it seems each VC in the NavController considers itself *presented by* the controller that presented the NavController... so...

You still don't need the extra `.tabBarController` part, but you also don't need to get a reference to the Nav Controller.

This code, in the *current* VC in `PlanSettingsViewController`, should get the proper reference to the tabBarController:

```
var thePresenter = self.presentingViewController as? MyPlanTabBarController
```

<s>So, to get a reference to the tabBarController from planInfoNavCon, you want to get its *presenter*:</s>

```
var thePresenter = self.navigationController?.presentingViewController
```

You don't want the extra `.tabBarController` part (may need other `?` unwrapping - I'm not actually running this code).

Comment: I have tried this. `self.navigationController?.presentingViewController as? MyPlanTabBarController` returns nil

Comment: Have you stepped through in Debug to inspect the values? Are you sure self.navigationController is valid at that point? If you *don't* cast it `as? MyPlanTabBarController`, what's the value / class of `self.navigationController?.presentingViewController`?

Comment: Yes I am in debug mode. `po self.navigationController` returns `<UINavigationController>` and `po self.navigationController?.presentingViewController` returns `<UIViewController>`. It fails when I try to cast it as TabBarController

Comment: Interesting... see my edit. Works for my quick test.

Comment: For me it returns nil when I try to cast as MyPlanTabBarController. Edited question to include screenshot.

Comment: Is that in your ViewController subclass? Or in your NavController subclass?

Comment: Hmmm... in my test, I'm presenting the NavVC *from* my subclassed Tab Controller. I'll try a couple edits and present it from a button tap in one of the Tab views...

Comment: Take a look at this if you want: https://github.com/DonMag/SWTabsWithSpecialTab .. branch: "NavVC-as-Special-Action" ... I had put it together a couple days ago to show presenting from a custom Tab button, so this fit in without much editing. You can present the NavController either from the button on Tab 2, or from the custom center button on the tab bar. Then check the code on "Tap to Return" button(s)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141498/discussion-between-sasquatch-and-donmag).